# How do I save WriteableBitmap to a file with a specific size with Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the following code in Windows Phone 7 to save a JPEG image with a specific size:

```
WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(resizedImage);
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
wBitmap.SaveJpeg(m, h, w, 0, 100);
```

I am getting the error:

```
"WritableBitmap does contain a definition for SaveJpeg"
```

How do I do the same thing on a desktop Windows Forms app with C#?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Can't be both.

Comment: @Clemens: Doesn't matter what belongs to who.  If its part of the framework, you can use it.

Comment: I am asking someone for help converting this code to Windows Forms desktop app FROM a Windows Phone 7 app.

Comment: @EthanAllen In order to use JpegBitmapEncoder you'd need to reference the PresentationCore assembly.

Comment: It's odd that you would go from a WP7 app to Windows Forms rather than WPF.  Coding Windows Forms nowadways is like coding ASP.NET instead of  ASP.NET MVC.  You're going to be wasting a lot more time and effort than is needed.

Comment: If you're using windows phone 7, make sure you reference Microsoft.Phone.dll. That was my problem cz i was working in a class library project and by default this dll is not referenced in this type of projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you would do this (okay, was facetious, now am srs) using the [JpegBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapencoder.jpegbitmapencoder.aspx)

```
//Assuming resizedImage is a BitmapSource
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(resizedImage));
using(var stream = File.Open(theAristocratsFilename))
    encoder.Save(stream);
```